# HTML Rename download link

Tags: javascript, html, download

I have a mp3 link like this :

```
http://example.com/932937293723.mp3
```

but i want to rename it when user downloads the file to be like this

```
http://example.com/Artist - Title.mp3
```

My code :

```
<a href="http://example.com/932937293723.mp3" download="Artist - Title.mp3">DOWNLOAD</a>
```

The mp3 file stored in remote server. And i'm not the owner of that server.
HTML `download` attribute seem not good solution. because it's not cross-browser. Any cross-browser solution to solve this ? Javascript maybe :D

Comment: can you show us your download code?

Comment: what is your back end coding language/ server technology

Comment: Related javascript demo: http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/a.download.html

Comment: `download` attribute is best solution in your circumstances. Otherwise you'll have to proxy this file through your server to add appropriate headers.

Comment: @Prasanth that's almost answer my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on working from the front end, try working with the following code. The getblob method is depreciated, but you need to update that side. Let me know.

```
function getBinary(file){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();  
    xhr.open("GET", file, false);  
    xhr.overrideMimeType("text/plain; charset=x-user-defined");  
    xhr.send(null);
    return xhr.responseText;
}
function sendBinary(data, url){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", url, true);

    if (typeof XMLHttpRequest.prototype.sendAsBinary == "function") { // Firefox 3 & 4
        var tmp = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) tmp += String.fromCharCode(data.charCodeAt(i) & 0xff);
        data = tmp;
    }
    else { // Chrome 9
        // http://javascript0.org/wiki/Portable_sendAsBinary
        XMLHttpRequest.prototype.sendAsBinary = function(text){
            var data = new ArrayBuffer(text.length);
            var ui8a = new Uint8Array(data, 0);
            for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) ui8a[i] = (text.charCodeAt(i) & 0xff);

            var bb = new BlobBuilder(); // doesn't exist in Firefox 4
            bb.append(data);
            var blob = bb.getBlob();
            this.send(blob);
        }
    }

    xhr.sendAsBinary(data); 
}

var data = getBinary("My music.mp3");
sendBinary(data,'http://www.tonycuffe.com/mp3/tailtoddle_lo.mp3');
```

Comment: Incredible. @Kevin you rock

Comment: let me save your code as reference :D. if you don't mind. could you show an example to get binary with progress bar

Comment: @MichaelAntonio happy to be of help, Bro :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like below (ASP.NET)

In ASPX

```
<a href="FileDownloader.aspx?file=encoded_url_to_mp3">Download</a>
```

In ASP.NET

```
Response.ContentType = "audio/mpeg3";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=New_file_name.mp3");
Server.Transfer(decoded_URL_of_MP3_file);
```

Look here for other [MIME](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/) types

Update#1 - Using Javascript alone, you can try something like this, though I've not tested in different browsers

```
function Download(url, fancyFileName) 
    {
    var file = document.createElement('a');
    file.href = url;
    file.target = '_blank';
    file.download = fancyFileName;

    var event = document.createEvent('Event');
    event.initEvent('click', true, true);
    file.dispatchEvent(event);
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(file.href);
    }

Download('http://server.com/file.mp3','Artist_file.mp3');
```

Comment: Not sure which server side technology OP is using

Comment: Yes, but the concept is to change the response content type and then transfer the file

Comment: @S.Krishna i can't change the source code. because the server not mine

Comment: I dont think thats possible then !

Comment: @S.Krishna i think it possible. Maybe with emulate `Save Link As with javascript

Answer (score 1):

In your back end code, you can fetch the file to your server, store it to a variable, rename it from there, define the corresponding headers, and return it. this could happen as an ajax call initiated on the javascript click.

Post further details about your backed and i can help you more.

Comment: Thx kevin. Good idea !, Could you give me a client side solution, please :)